# Perform $gte and $lt on the same field _id in MongoDB

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

`db.comments.find({"_id" : {"$gte": ObjectId("6225f932a7bce76715a9f3bd"), "$lt":ObjectId("6225f932a7bce76715a9f3bd")}}).sort({"created_datetime":1}).limit(10).pretty()`

I am using this query which should give me the current "6225f932a7bce76715a9f3bd" doc, 4 docs inserted before this and 5 docs inserted after this. But currently when i run this query, i get null result. Where am i going wrong ??

Comment: `find` method returns a _cursor_. In case there are documents matching the filter, you have an empty cursor - not a `null` as result.

Comment: Note that `"_id" >= X` **and** `"_id" < X` is an empty set.  Your query would not give you ``the current "6225f932a7bce76715a9f3bd" doc, 4 docs inserted before this and 5 docs inserted after this''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no other option but to seperate my queries in order to achieve my expectation.

```
        query = request.args.to_dict()
        find_query = {}
        find_query["_id"] = {"$lt": ObjectId(query["comment_id"])}
        previous_comments = list(db.comments.find(find_query))
        find_query["_id"] = {"$gte": ObjectId(query["comment_id"])}
        next_comments =  list(db.comments.find(find_query))
        previous_comments.extend(next_comments)
        return {"comments":previous_comments}
```